# Data driven gitflow tests

Tags: c#, specflow, data-driven-tests, ddt

Can provide a datasource for gitlow tests?
I don't want t use scenario outlines but I want to be able to run each specflow test with different configuration.
Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you want to use scenario outlines? This is the standard way to run the same test several times with different configurations.

Comment: The problem is that I want data to be dynamicaly generated.

Comment: Why do you need data dynamically generated? One of the main reasons for writing BDD tests is to make them perfectly reproducible every test run. With random data, you introduce instability in the system. It sounds like you either need to create more scenarios to test edge cases, or go with a Scenario Outline.

Comment: Why do you think that the data will be random? It's not random, but just provided by the third-party source.